# Mongo update not working with my array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to update one of my array field with another array but it doesn't work.

Here's the code :

```
var Dungeon = require('./dungeon.js');
var DBDungeon = require('../database/dungeons.js'); 

sio.on('connection', function(socket){
    var username = socket.request.session.passport.user.username;
    socket.on('init', function(data){
        var dname = data.name;
        var type = data.type;
        DBDungeon.findOne({'name':dname}, function(err, d){
            var dungeon = new Dungeon.Dungeon(d);
            socket.on("disconnect",function(){
                    console.log(dungeon.blocks);
                    DBDungeon.update({'name':dname},{'$set': {'blocks':dungeon.blocks}}, function(err, result){if(err)console.log(err)});
                    dungeonHandler.remove(socket.id);
                });
        });
    });
});
```

and the schema

```
var dungeonsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name      : {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    owner     : {type: String, required: true},
    blocks    : {type: [[Number]]},
});
```

During the update, I get this error :
[TypeError: Cannot read property 'castForQuery' of undefined]

Comment: Have you tried using mongoose findOneAndUpdate() ? Very easy to use, I can show you an example if you want?

Comment: I tried and i got the same error.